# What is the Big O analysis of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o, time-complexity

I'm working on a data structures course and I'm not sure how to proceed w/ this Big O analysis:

```
sum = 0;
for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
     for(j = 1; j < i*i; j++)
         if(j % i == 0)
             for(k = 0; k < j; k++)
                   sum++;
```

My initial idea is that this is O(n^3) after reduction, because the innermost loop will only run when `j`/`i` has no remainder and the multiplication rule is inapplicable.  Is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: This might be best asked on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Let's ignore the outer loop for a second here, and let's analyze it in terms of `i`.

The mid loop runs `i^2` times, and is invoking the inner loop whenever `j%i == 0`, that means you run it on `i, 2i, 3i, ...,i^2`, and at each time you run until the relevant `j`, this means that the inner loop summation of running time is:

```
i + 2i + 3i + ... + (i-1)*i  = i(1 + 2 + ... + i-1) = i* [i*(i-1)/2]
```

The last equality comes from [sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

The above is in `O(i^3)`.

repeat this to the outer loop which runs from `1` to `n` and you will get running time of `O(n^4)`, since you actually have:

```
C*1^3 + C*2^3 + ... + C*(n-1)^3 = C*(1^3 + 2^3 + ... + (n-1)^3) = 
= C/4 * (n^4 - 2n^3 + n^2)
```

The last equation comes from [sum of cubes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%5E3+%2B+2%5E3+%2B+3%5E3+%2B+...+%2B+%28n-1%29%5E3)

And the above is in **`O(n^4)`**, which is your complexity.

Comment: inner loop do not run when `j = i^2` since j-loop end after loop body for `j = i^2 - 1`

Comment: @hk6279 Thank you. Obviously it does not influence the big O notation, but you're 100% correct. Fixed.

Comment: I think this answer is missing a minor detail. You also need to count the number of times `j%i == 0` is checked. It turns out of course it is checked only `O(i^2)` times compared to `O(i^3)` executions of the innermost statement, so `O(i^3)` wins out. But if it the condition were instead something like `if (j <= 10)`, your analysis would be incorrect.

Comment: @C-S I avoided it because it is pretty obvious this number is smaller (asymptotically) then `i^3`.

Comment: @amit OK, but if someone wrote that it was "pretty obvious" on a CS theory problem set, I would dock them points ;)